# Input text without previously entered value

Tags: html, input, xhtml, textinput

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

I entered a value in input text for example: email@email.com, after when I entering another value same area, seems the previously entered data (email@email.com).But I don't want to appear it. How can I do this?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag

Comment: information entered is kept in cache?information accessible using firebug with this trick?

Answer (score 0):

You could use "placeholder"

```
<input type="text" placeholder="email@email.com">
```

Comment: I thought that too, but he wants to disable the browser autocompletion.

Comment: Then the link provided by cem would do the trick