# Make text input fields remember previously entered data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My text inputs seem not to remember values that have been typed before. For example, many websites that I don't even have an account on, but have, for example entered my email address before (buying a train ticket as a "guest") give me a sort of dropdown with email addresses I've used in the past. Yet my form does not do this. It obliges me to type it out completely every time. It seems to be the opposite of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607378/input-text-without-previously-entered-value)...

I have simple inputs like `<input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="First name" />`

And they are submitted with simple a jQuery Ajax post. Something like [this](http://jsbin.com/utepax/2/edit). However the Ajax isn't working on jsbin on that example, I just show it to demonstrate my basic structure. Is there a jQuery plugin for this? Is there a way I can control this seemingly browser-driven behavior?

Comment: _many websites that I don't even have an account on_ .. Website's don't remember those values. It's remembered by browser.

Comment: As you understand, it is browser driven. I don't think you can do anything when your browser setting says otherwise.

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem.  For me, it was when developing in ASP.NET MVC. Anyway, the solution I had to make was a combination of things:

1. Having the name attribute defined in my input tags
2. Having `autocomplete="on"` in my input tags
3. Changing the button tag to be a `type="submit"` tag
4. Enclosing all my input controls in a `<form>` tag

Comment: In Firefox, I couldn't get this to work until I followed all these steps. The highest voted answer wasn't enough. For what it's worth, I'm making a single page app.

Answer (score 20):

In most browsers, you can make your browser display values previously entered in input fields by giving a name to the input. For example:

```
<input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="First name" name="firstName" >
```

If the field has no name attribute, the browser won't show suggestions.

Also check if javascript prevents the default action on submit.

Comment: is it still true? It seems browsers have a lot more heuristics now for autofill

Answer (score 5):

some browsers adamantly refused to remember an input until i "remembered it manually" via (ab)using localStorage... this worked for me:

```js
    {
        // hack to remember last error id on page refresh
        // can't believe i have to do this, but my browser don't want to remember it itself, 
        // ... not sure why
        let errorid_element=document.querySelector("#errorlog_id");
        let rememberHack=function(){
            localStorage.setItem("last_id_remember_hack",errorid_element.value);
        };
        errorid_element.addEventListener("input",rememberHack);
        errorid_element.addEventListener("change",rememberHack);
        errorid_element.value = localStorage.getItem("last_id_remember_hack");
    }
```

Comment: It is an stable and reliable workaround =)

Comment: @user3405291 indeed, far more reliable than the "autocomplete" property everyone else is promoting, in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

It may vary depending on the browser and user privacy settings and sorts, and it should be on by default, but try adding `autocomplete="on"` to your input tag.

Comment: autocomplete="on" should be the default. If the browser doesn't remember, we can't override it

Comment: The spec says default is on - http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-autocomplete-attribute

Comment: The default `autocomplete` value for input fields is on so setting this attribute should not really do anything. This setting is a browser driven setting. If the user's settings in the browser do not allow for remembering autocomplete values, nothing you add, change, modify, alter, create etc. is going to change this. The user would need to update their browser settings to allow for this.

Comment: This worked for me. A framework I was using must have had it turned off. Thanks for keeping up the answer even with negative points.

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap you would fill up the for='' field

Example:

```
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox checkbox-lg">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="TER" value="TER">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="TER">Land/Lot</label>
    </div>
```

^ Notice how **for** and **id** values match

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React

- give each input a name
- wrap in `<form>`
- prevent default form action
- add `type="submit"` on any submission buttons, and do not include `onClick`. Let the `onSubmit` callback handle that.

Now hitting enter or clicking the button will remember the value entered.

```
<form onSubmit={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent new page from being opened
        // do something with input data
     }
}>
    <input name="myInput" ... />
    <button type="submit" ... />
</form>
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 0):

The below worked well for me. I'm copying and pasting the chunks that matter so you may need to tweak it slightly to get it to work for you but it should largely "just work".

```
$(function(){
  function save_user_inputs(ev){
    $("input").each(function(index, $input){
      if ($input.name == ""){
        return true;
      }       
      localStorage.setItem("input." + $input.name, $input.value);
    }); 
    return true;
  } 

  function load_user_inputs(){
    var input_names = Object.keys(localStorage);
    for(var i=0; i<input_names.length; i++){
      var input_name = input_names[i];
      if (!input_name.startsWith("input.")){
        continue;
      }   
      var $input = $("[name='"+input_name.split(".")[1]+"']")
      $input.val(localStorage[input_name]);
    }   
  } 
        
  $(document).on('submit', save_user_inputs);
  load_user_inputs();
});
```

Answer (score -4):

You may try `autocomplete="on"`

```
<input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="First name" autocomplete="on" />
```

Comment: It depends on the browser. The spec says default is on - http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-autocomplete-attribute

Comment: @thomas Check you browser Autocomplete setting. Which browser you are using ?

Comment: The default `autocomplete` value for input fields is on so setting this attribute should not really do anything. This setting is a browser driven setting. If the user's settings in the browser do not allow for remembering autocomplete values, nothing you add, change, modify, alter, create etc. is going to change this. The user would need to update their browser settings to allow for this.

Answer (score -6):

Add attribute `autocomplete="off"` to your input.

Comment: This question is nearly five years old. And your solution is anyway clearly the opposite of the desired behavior.