# Sapui5 autocomplete input

Tags: input, autocomplete, sapui5, history

I'm developing an app with a login and I need use an autocomplete input. In HTML is easy to develop it, but I don't know how to implement.

I find a solution where set data to the input, but in my case, I can't do it.

Example:

First Time: Log with the name: "Name1"
Second Time: Log with the name: "Name2"
Third Time: When the user write "N", the input must show "Name1", "Name2"

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add browser cache autocomplete in SAPUI5 Input field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42778647/how-to-add-browser-cache-autocomplete-in-sapui5-input-field)

Answer (score 2):

Please use [sap.m.Input](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Input.html) and set it's property [showSuggestion](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Input.html#setShowSuggestion) to true, also bind suggestionItems as in this [example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.InputSuggestionsCustomFilter/preview).

Comment: But the problem is that I don't have model to bind. If the user write "example" the next time this user start to write "ex.." the input need to show "example" as a suggestion

Comment: Create model, bind it to sap.m.Input and then when user writes "example" save it to the model and next time when one writes "e" "example" will be suggested.

Comment: But when the user restart the app, this model will be lost

Comment: You can save it to hdd.

Comment: There is no way to do like html5? just indicate to the input "Autocomplete"

Comment: Sorry, I do not know html5, what do you mean?

Comment: In HTML if you set the attribute "autocomplete" = "on" this proccess is automatical

Comment: @PabloGarcia hello from the future. Did you able to solve problem with native html5 attributes. I don't want to use, suggestionItems or sapui5 suggestion system. autcomplete=off is disabled by default, do you have any solution for this problem